# In Angular 8 /9, can I determine my URL inside of app.module.ts and use it when declaring modules?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, angular8, angular9

I have a third party module in my app.module.ts that needs to know whether a user logs in with or without a "www" in their url to correctly redirect them after authentication. So, setup looks like:

**app.module.ts**

```
...
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports     : [
        ...
        ThirdPartyAuthModule.initAuth(environment.authConfig),
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap   : [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

I want to get somehow get the url into that authConfig variable. Is this possible with Angular?

Comment: you can actually use `APP_INITIALIZER` and write your logic in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use window.location.href

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-href-1

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

const authConfig = environment.authConfig;
// Add param below to your auth config
const href = window.location.href;
const isHttp = href.includes('http://');
const isHttps = href.includes('https://');
const hasWWW = href.includes('www');;

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    // ThirdPartyAuthModule.initAuth(authConfig),
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```